# What is this "cyclic inheritance" called in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I saw a code like this the other day:

```
type
    TFather = class;
    TSon = class(TFather);
    TFather = class(TSon);
end;
```

Son inherited from Father that inherited from Son.
Searched for Cyclic Inheritance but only Java results.

What is this called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example code (that's now been deleted) doesn't do what you think it does. You see `TMycxGridDBTableView` being defined as a descendant of `TcxGridDBTableView`, and then you see `TcxGridDBTableView`, defined as a descendant of `TcxGridDBTableView`.

However, the `TcxGridDBTableView` you see at the top is not the same `TcxGridDBTableView` that you see later. The first one refers to a class declared elsewhere, in some other unit. The next occurrence is declaring a *new* class in *this* unit that happens to have the same base name as the other unit's class.

This technique is known as an **interposer class**. It's used to introduce a new `GetViewDataClass` method, but still end up with the same class name. The form that uses controls with that name will use the new version of the class instead of the original version. It's a way to customize a VCL control without having to compile and install a custom package.

Comment: Nice, after -2 votes I thought I was never getting an answer, I guess you can't make a mistake even you're not sure what you are talking about.
Why was the example code deleted? Copyright or something?

Comment: I deleted it because it changed the question. You should have heeded the advice in my comments and asked a new question.

Comment: @David: But it was meant to be an example of what he described, i.e. TSon inheriting from TFather and TFather from TSon. That the first TFather was in another unit was not immediately obvious.

Comment: @rudy the question as was originally asked was clear and was answered. Obviously Lucas asked the wrong question. That's fine. His next move was to ask a new question with the correct example. Think of the future readers. It is not helpful to have answers to two completely different questions alongside each other. It is one question at a time here at SO.

Comment: @David: ISTM it was the same question, just with more information from his part (even if that information did not *prove* what he thought to have seen, it clearly *demonstrated* what he meant and why he had the impression that there was cyclic inheritance going on there).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I also think that question edit should be reverted and then Rob can modify his answer with additional information that would both approaches shown in code examples where approach shown in the code that is visible now is known as `Forward declaration` while approach that is used in now deleted code example is known as class interception as it is stated in Rob's answer. That way this question  be even more helpful as it explains two concepts which are commonly mistaken for so called cyclic inheritance which isn't even possible on Object Pascal as in some other languages.

Comment: You can all over rule me if you want. I saw a perfectly clear question with multiple clear answers. And I saw an edit which asked a different question. If you all want to over rule and edit the question do so. But think what to do with the three answers that will then become invalid. What is your proposed solution to that?

Comment: @silver the code in the original question is a compiler error as explained by the other answers.

Comment: Lucas, now you need to unaccept this answer so Rob can remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Nonsense. You can have TSon with a property of type TFather, and TFather with a property TSon, but what you have written is pure nonsense.

The following makes some sense, but has no special term, since there is no recursion:

```
type
  TFather = class;
  TSon = class
    public
      Father : TFather;
  end;
  TFather = class
    public
       Son : TSon;
  end;
```

Comment: Indeed, that is possibly what the OP really saw.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what it is called, but it doesn't make sense. It is simply impossible.

If I try to compile this code:

```
type
  TFather = class;
  TSon = class(TFather)
  end;
  TFather = class(TSon)
  end;
```

I get:

```
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(12): E2086 Type 'TFather' is not yet completely defined
```

and that is as expected.

Cyclic inheritance **is an error condition** in Java. You get a diagnostic mentioning "cyclic inheritance" if something like this is happening directly or indirectly (i.e. with a few classes inbetween). In other words, it is not a programming concept, it is an error condition.

Comment: FWIW I think in Java and also C# (there is is the compile error [CS0146](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kty4k630.aspx)) this diagnostic information makes sense and is necessary because you can have those classes in different files but in the same namespace so they know each other. In Delphi because of the way forward declarations and circular uses prevent you from doing so it is not.

Comment: @Stefan: indeed. But it is not a concept, it is an error situation. I can't imagine the OP saw this in real code.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this called?

The technical term is *syntax error*. This code is illegal.